# Problems with EditText field not showing up

Tags: android, android-edittext

Am very new to Android programming, so sorry if this is a simple problem.

I'm trying to create a form to input user data, and I keep getting the following error:

> "Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@6279d588"

This is what my xml looks like for the layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">"
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a test\nsecond line\n"/>
       <EditText android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="@string/compose_name"></EditText>                  
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_contact_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is what my class file looks like:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_contact);

        //Set up handlers for input text
        //nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        //name = nameField.getText().toString();

        final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        nameField.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    String strNicknameToSave = nameField.getText().toString();
                    // TODO: Save Nickname setting (strNicknameToSave)
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_contact_button);

        // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

If I get rid of the EditText field, then it works fine.  Also it ran perfectly just once, but I haven't been able to repeat that (all I did in the meantime was delete another layout that isn't being used).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you edit -  We can't see the XML layout at all.

Comment: If that's what your XML looks like, we may have found the problem already ;)

Comment: Your xml cannot be viewed. To put codes, make 4 spaces in starting of line instead of using ">".

Comment: Thanks for advice on how to show xml.

Comment: That goes for any code, BTW--Java, C, whatever. Except maybe whitespace. 

Is the rest of your layout showing up, or are you getting a black screen? Have you tried running without adding the `KeyListener`, or adding one with an empty `onKey` instead of the closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Don't declare nameField as 'final' - see if that works.

**EDIT:** Ah, OK sorry, I wasn't thinking straight. Have your Activity implement the listener instead of creating it inline and have nameField as an instance member...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
    implements View.onKeyListener {

    EditText nameField = null; // <-- Instance member

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_contact);

        nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        nameField.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                String strNicknameToSave = nameField.getText().toString();
                // TODO: Save Nickname setting (strNicknameToSave)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I get a compile error: "local variable nameField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final"

Comment: @TechnoTony: Sorry, see my EDIT in my answer. I personally try to avoid inline listener creation, they cause problems if not done right. Just implement the listener on your Activity.

Comment: @TechnoTony: Good to hear. Good luck.